# hexadecimal floating constant in C

Tags: c, constants, hex

`0x0.3p10` represents what value?

And what's the meaning of the `p` in the statement above?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`0x0.3p10` is an example of a *hexadecimal floating point literal*, introduced in C99<sup>(1)</sup>. The `p` separates the base number from the exponent.

The `0x0.3` bit is called the significand part (whole with optional fraction) and the exponent is the power of two by which it is scaled.

That particular value is calculated as `0.3` in hex, or `3 * 16-1` (`3/16`) multiplied by `210` (`1024`), which gives `3 * 1024 / 16` or `192`. The following program confirms this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    double d = 0x0.3p10;
    printf ("%.f\n", d); // Outputs 192
    return 0;
}
```

Section `6.4.4.2 Floating constants` of C99 has all the details:

> A floating constant has a significand part that may be followed by an exponent part and a suffix that specifies its type. The components of the significand part may include a digit sequence representing the whole-number part, followed by a period `.`, followed by a
> digit sequence representing the fraction part.

> The components of the exponent part are an `e`, `E`, `p`, or `P` followed by an exponent consisting of an optionally signed digit sequence. Either the whole-number part or the fraction part has to be present; for decimal floating constants, either the period or the exponent part has to be present.

> The significand part is interpreted as a (decimal or hexadecimal) rational number; the digit sequence in the exponent part is interpreted as a decimal integer. For decimal floating constants, the exponent indicates the power of 10 by which the significand part is to be scaled. For hexadecimal floating constants, the exponent indicates the power of 2 by which the significand part is to be scaled.

> For decimal floating constants, and also for hexadecimal floating constants when `FLT_RADIX` is not a power of 2, the result is either the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. For hexadecimal floating constants when `FLT_RADIX` is a power of 2, the result is correctly rounded.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> These literals were also added to C++ in the C++17 iteration of the standard, though the ability to format and parse them was part of C++11.

Comment: Hi, Then what decimal value it stand for? Does the `p` stand for some english word? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Is this usable in C++?

Comment: @Benoit, I don't think so - C++0x 2.14.4 details the floating literals and there's no mention of the `p` variant in there.

Comment: @Benoit [added in C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)

Comment: @rampion Thanks for the notification! Always impressive.

Comment: Also, since C++11 it's supported in printf & scanf.

Comment: @NanoHE the P might stand for precision.

Comment: @bitRAKE: it's not really related to precision though. I suppose it *could* be power?

Comment: @paxdiablo yeah, binary power makes more sense.

Comment: comment for anyone dense like me: `0x0.3p10` has everything prior to the `p` in base 16 (so it could be 0xf.fp10) but the value after `p` is in base10, while the thing being exponentiated is `2` and not `10`, so it's `value * 2^10`  It's a lot...