# MAXFLOAT in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point

Max float is defied as:

*math.h*

```
#define    MAXFLOAT    0x1.fffffep+127f
```

I'm a little sad I never noticed this before.  What's this actually say?  I would have expected something like this:

```
#define    MAXFLOAT    0xFFFFFFFF-1
```

Would that even work?

Comment: related: [hexadecimal floating constant in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825824/hexadecimal-floating-constant-in-c)

Comment: Is that specific to Objective-C?  And is it `MAX_FLOAT` or `MAXFLOAT`?  C has `FLT_MAX` in `<float.h>`; since Objective-C is so strongly backwards compatible with C, I'd expect it to just use that.

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF-1` is an integer expression, so it wouldn't work for `MAX(_)FLOAT` -- nor would it have the right value.

Comment: @KeithThompson: it's not specific to Objective-C; it's required for UNIX conformance.

Comment: @StephenCanon: You're right.  It's spelled `MAXFLOAT`, and POSIX says it's obsolescent.  Use `FLT_MAX` in `<float.h>` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0x1.fffffep+127` is (roughly)
1.99999999999999999999998 times 2^127.  It's a floating point number, with an exponent, in hexadecimal.

- `0x` = hex notation
- `1` = integer part of the number
- `.fffffe` = fractional part of the number
- `p+127` = scientific notation for "times two to the 127th power"

Comment: besides `p` and `e` are there more scientific notation syntax?

Comment: [The ISO standard for the C programming language](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/) only uses `p` and `e` – other languages may vary, but most of the popular languages (Perl, Python, Java, anything derived from C) use at least the `e` syntax.

Comment: So then what signifies `e` in this instance from being part of the number, instead of `p`?  Is the literal only allowed before the `+`?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because it's hex, so you can't use E, you have to go higher, the `p` literal is simply something outside A-F?

Comment: The difference is that `e` is a power-of-ten exponent ("times _ten_ to the nth power"), and `p` is a power-of-two exponent ("times _two_ to the nth power"); syntax-wise you can't put a hexadecimal number with a decimal exponent (or vice versa), and you generally wouldn't want to.

Answer (score 5):

`MAXFLOAT` is required for UNIX conformance:

> > MAXFLOAT
> >
> > [XSI]  Value of maximum non-infinite single-precision floating-point number.

`0x1.fffffep+127f` is precisely that value, represented as a standard C hexadecimal floating-point literal.

The C standard requires that `FLT_MAX` be defined in `<float.h>`, and it has the same value ("maximum representable finite floating-point number", per §5.2.4.2.2).  `FLT_MAX` is the more portable choice, as it is required by the language standard.

Comment: And POSIX says that `MAXFLOAT` is obsolescent.