# PostgreSQL: Constant for smallint maximum value?

Tags: postgresql, constants

Does PostgreSQL have a constant (like [MAXFLOAT in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420131/maxfloat-in-objective-c)) for the maximum value that a `smallint` can be?

I know the [PostgreSQL numeric types documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html) says it's `32767`, but I'd rather use a constant than hard coding a value that could change.

I'm using this number to prevent an error when incrementing a `smallint`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE populations
SET count = count + 1
WHERE city_id = 3
AND count < 32767;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the size of `smallint` is specified by the SQL standard, so it is vanishingly unlikely that it will change. You might still want a constant to make the intention clear, in which case Neil McGuigan's answer would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Create it:

```
create function MAX_SMALLINT() returns smallint immutable language sql as '
  select 32767::smallint;
';
```

Use it:

```
UPDATE populations
SET count = count + 1
WHERE city_id = 3
AND count < MAX_SMALLINT();
```

Comment: That's nice but is still hard-coded. What if PostgreSQL changes the max?

Comment: then you alter your function body. I wouldn't call that hard coding.

Answer (score 1):

In extension of Neil's suggestion, you could use this:

```
create function MAX_SMALLINT() returns smallint immutable language sql as '
    select ((1 << ((pg_column_size(1::smallint) << 3) - 1)) - 1)::smallint;
';
```

But honestly, I don't believe smallint will ever be anything else than 2 bytes in Postgres.

Comment: Funnily this works for smallint, but not for integer: if I replace `smallint` by `integer`, it shows `SQL Error [22003]: ERROR: integer out of range` :-(