# Invalid suffix "-252" on integer constant

Tags: c, integer

I've been trying to run a C file from https://github.com/amree/mykad-c/blob/master/scdump.c, but I keep getting `Invalid suffix "-252" on integer constant` at this part of the code:

```
        if (RxBuffer[0x11E-252] == 'P')
            printf("Female\n");
        else if (RxBuffer[0x11E-252] == 'L')
            printf("Male\n");
        else
            printf("%c\n", RxBuffer[0x11E-252]);
```

I'm pretty sure it's syntax related. But I don't really understand code (I'm trying to, but I'm pretty much stuck). Can anyone help me?

Comment: What compiler are you using? This is a compiler bug that was present in gcc 2.95, perhaps early gcc 3.x, and perhaps other compilers.

Comment: @R. - this error occurs for me with a fairly recent gcc 4.6.1 - there's a bug closed as "RESOLVED INVALID": http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3885  There's an open bug that's tracking making the diagnostic friendlier: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24976

Comment: @R..: I'm using Qt Framework, so I guess I'm using GCC compiler? I got the same error on Windows (MingW) and Linux (modified to use pcsc-lite) (gcc 4.5.2)

Comment: See my comments on the accepted answer. GCC is doing the right thing, but the answer's explanation of it is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While this problem is related in a way to hex floating point constants, the root cause of the problem isn't because `0x11E` is the start of a hex float constant (because it's not the start of a hex floating constant).

The problem is that `0x11E-252` is a single token instead of three tokens like `0x11F-252` is.  If you look at C99 6.4.8 "Preprocessing numbers", you'll see that a pp-number token is:

> A preprocessing number begins with a digit optionally preceded by a period (.)and may be followed by valid identifier characters and the character sequences e+, e-, E+, E-, p+, p-, P+, or P-

So, `0x11E-252` is a single token and tokenizing occurs in translation phase 3, but when it comes time to interpret the token syntactically and semantically (which happens in translation phase 7), it's not syntactically valid so you get a compiler error.

On the other hand, `0x11F-252` is three tokens because the `-` is not part of a preprocessing number token unless it's immediately preceded by a `P` or `E` (upper or lowercase).

Of course, this is related to float constants (hexadecimal or otherwise) because that's why the `-` character can end up in the middle of a preprocessing number token. However, note that you will get a similar error messages for tokens like `0xx11F` or `22bad_token` which have no resemblance to a hex floating point constant.

The fix is [as ouah noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977981/12711), insert whitespace before the `-` to force the compiler to treat the sequence as more than one token. If this were your code, an even better solution might be to give names to all those magic numbers (enums or macros). An identifier followed by `-` won't be considered a single token.  Plus you'd hopefully have the bonus of making the code a little more self documenting.

Comment: See the end of http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Incompatibilities.html for explicit GCC documentation on this issue.

Answer (score 6):

```
0x11E-252
```

is an hexadecimal floating point constant in C and `-252` is the exponent part. You get the warning because you are initializing an integer object with a float constant.

```
0x11E - 252  // Note the whitespace
```

is an integer expression.

Use the latter to have the desired behavior.

**EDIT**:

my answer is actually not true. While the fix is OK, see the answer from [@MichaelBurr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977943/invalid-suffix-252-on-integer-constant/11979001) for the real explanation of what's going on. `0x11E-252` is a read as a single token under C rules and it is not a valid floating (or integer) number.

Comment: This is not a warning, this is an error, because hex FP constants use `p` instead of `e` (since `e` is a valid hex digit). Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4825867/335858) explaining hex float constants of C99.

Comment: Well I meant warning in the sense of C diagnostic.

Comment: Ah, I see. Nice answer, by the way (+1).

Comment: This is wrong. It's not a hex float constant. OP's compiler is buggy and wrongly treating it as one. The exponent character in hex floats is `P` not `E`.

Comment: Hmm.. Even though the error is gone and I can compile happily, I can't produce the correct value by just adding space in the front. This code used to work (the repo has its binary and it produces the correct value).

Comment: OK, it's not a hex float, but it is a preprocessor token, and thus the C language requires it to be parsed as a single token and therefore treated as an error.

Comment: @foo: I don't know if it's the cause of the difference you're seeing, but this line in `TrimString()` has undefined behavior: `for (j=0; j<i+1; out[j++]=in[j]);` - gcc may well compile that differently than VC++ (and even with VC++ you can't be sure how it'll compile).  Try replacing it with `for (j=0; j<i+1; ++j) out[j]=in[j];`

Comment: @foo could you accept MichaelBurr answer instead of mine, so I can delete my answer?