# How to write an octal floating point literal in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, octal

Somehow i have always assumed that floating point and integer values are processed the same except one would have a '.' character.

So for the code like this:

```
auto i = 0100;
std::cout << i;
```

I get the expected output `64`;

However, when i try the following code:

```
auto d = 0100.0;
std::cout << d;
```

I get output `100`, which is not what was expected. Now it is possible that the floating point part does not deal with a leading 0. So i have attempted something which really should have worked:

```
auto d = 1.0e-010;
std::cout << d;
```

Since exponent is actually an integer value itself, it made sense that it would understand the octal value, but the output was `1e-10`.

Is this an issue that comes from the standard or from g++ (my compiler)? How would i go about writing an octal floating point number?

Hexadecimal seem to behave differently:

```
auto d = 0x100.0;
```

Gives `error: hexadecimal floating constants require an exponent`

However:

```
auto d = 0x1e3;
std::cout << d;
```

produces `483`. While

```
auto d = 0x1e0x3;
```

Gives `error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator"" x3’`

Comment: AFAIK there are no octal floating-point literals in C++.

Comment: What have you tried (besides this)?  Where did you get stuck?  What did you research?

Comment: Seriously? Why on earth do you want an octal floating point literal?

Comment: I think it's a perfectly legitimate question. I was just curious.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Sorry for overreaction. I have no *need* for it, that is immediate. Am trying to expand my knowledge of some aspects of the language.

Comment: We are talking here about a language that you can study for a decade and you'll still have plenty of dark corners left in it... Why don't you study something you actually *need*?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath one studies what one is interested in. There may be nothing one needs at the moment, so why not study interesting things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[user2079303](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079303/user2079303) and [blojayble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4638322/blojayble) have both given excellent answers, however, both were a bit incomplete. So here is expansion on both of them and additional information which was found.

**There are no octal floating point numbers in C++… for a reason**

The standard does not define octal floating point numbers, and compilers obey this particular rule to the letter. Leading `0` is read as just another decimal digit in the whole part or in the exponent.

Potential reason for this is the ambiguity of the number like `0.2`. Most people would mean by this ⅕; while if octal floating point numbers were a reality it would be ¼ for the same reason why `0` is an octal literal ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895522/is-0-a-decimal-literal-or-an-octal-literal)).

**There are no hexadecimal floating point numbers in C++, but…**

…, but there are in C. So many compilers allow one to use them, but they are a bit weird.

Firstly, they do not work without an exponent part. So writing 0x12a.b3 will likely not work.

Secondly, in hexadecimal notation `e` is not an exponent, since it's a digit 14. Therefore, `p` is used (probably meaning something like "power").

Thirdly, the exponent is hexadecimal is not 10 (of course), but it is not 16 (for some reason). Rather it is 2. So `0x12.4p3` becomes ( 1×16¹ + 2×16⁰ + 4×16⁻¹ ) × 2³ = ( 16 + 2 + ¼ ) × 8 = 146.

**It is relatively trivial to define own literals in C++11**

[blojayble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4638322/blojayble) has provided own realisation, but i thought that it would be best to redo it making it into a `constexpr`. The end result is the following code:

```
constexpr unsigned long long operator"" _oct(unsigned long long l)
{
    return
        (l < 9) ? l :
        operator"" _oct(l/10)*8 + l%10;
}
constexpr long double operator"" _oct(long double d)
{
    return
        (d == 0) ? 0.0 :
        (d < 1) ? 0.125*(((int)(d*10)) + operator"" _oct(d*10-((int)(d*10)))) :
        operator"" _oct((unsigned long long)d) + operator"" _oct(d-(unsigned long long)d);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Floating point literals cannot be written in octal in C++. You'll have to settle for decimal.

Standard C++ doesn't allow hexadecimal floating point literals either. However, C does (since C99) and compilers supporting it may allow hexadecimal in C++ too as an extension to the language.

> Hexadecimal seem to behave differently

Yes. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825867/2079303) for details on how to write hexadecimal floating point literals.

Answer (score 2):

You could make one yourself using C++11's user defined literals.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

long double operator"" _oct (long double oct)
{
    int i = 0;
    long double rem, fract, decimal = 0.0;
    long whole = (long)oct;
    fract = oct - whole;

    // whole part
    while (whole != 0)
    {
        rem = fmod(whole,10);
        whole/=10;
        decimal += rem*pow(8,i++);
    }
    i = 1; 
    // fractional part
    while(fract != 0){
        fract *= 10;
        rem = round(fract);
        decimal += rem*pow(8,-i++);
        fract -= rem;
    }
    return decimal;
}

int main() {
    cout << 10.1_oct; //8.125
    return 0;
}
```