# Smallest float X s.t. 1/X is not infinity

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

What is the smallest single and double precision float such that its reciprocal is still not equal infinity under IEEE 754?

**Edit:** I'm asking it because I just want to understand how it works

Comment: Brute force it.

Comment: The question is theoretical about C floating point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use IEEE 754 double-precision as an example. We assume that it is mapped to `double` in our C compilation platform. [C99 hexadecimal notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825824/hexadecimal-floating-constant-in-c) is convenient so we'll take advantage of it. Let us also assume that `long double` has at least one extra bit of precision over `double`, for instance, `long double` is Intel's 80-bit “extended double“.

The `double` operation `1.0 / x` rounds to `+inf` if and only if the mathematical result of the division is above the number `1.fffffffffffff8p1023L`. This number is not representable as a `double`, but it is exactly the midpoint between `DBL_MAX` and what would be the next `double` value after `DBL_MAX` if the `double` exponent had a wider range. This is how IEEE 754 defines whether basic operations such as `/` should round to infinity.

Therefore, the highest value `double` value to round to `+inf` when reciprocated can be computed with the following steps:

- set the rounding mode to `FE_DOWNWARD`
- compute `1.0L / 1.fffffffffffff8p1023L`
- (while still in round-downwards mode) round the result to `double`.

The smallest value not to round to infinity is the one just after that. It can be computed with `nextafter`, as standardized e.g. [in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nextafter.html).

Translating these four steps to C should be straightforward (do not forget `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`). Or, as Thomas Weller recommended, brute-force it. A search by dichotomy would take less than 64 steps.

NOTE: it is possible to compute the smallest value that reciprocates to a finite result by using the `FE_UPWARD` rounding mode and only three steps, but this relies on the additional property that `1.0L / 1.fffffffffffff8p1023L` cannot be an exact operation. The four-step method is conceptually cleaner.