# How to print floating point value from st(0) in assembly 8086 dosbox

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox, i386

Im trying to display the floating point in dosbox in order for debuging. 
I think the floating point number is store as IEEE 754 single precision. Due the the constraint im only able to use dosbox, hence im not able to use extern _printf to print the floating point in the assembly file. Is this possible to print floating point number in assembly 8086 dosbox? Thanks!

.code

```
a dd 3.2
z dd 2.5
```

main proc

```
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

finit
fldpi
fld [a]
fld [z]
fsub st(0),st(1)

mov eax,st(0)
mov dl,10
div dl

add ah,30h
mov dl,ah   
mov ah,02h
int 21h 

add al,30h
mov ah,02h
mov dl,al
int 21h

mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
```

Comment: There are C implementations for 8086, you could find a `printf` implementation there.  Otherwise, what format do you want?  The option that probably takes the least code is "hex float" representation, like `0x1.fp3` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Hex-Floats.html or [hexadecimal floating constant in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4825824)): mantissa in hex, base-2 exponent in decimal.  This format can exactly represent every IEEE binary32 in a fixed amount of digits, unlike a decimal format (where infinite repeating fractions are not uncommon)

Comment: BTW, `mov eax,st(0)` doesn't exist.  Do you want to round your float to the nearest integer, like `fistp dword [bp-4]` / `mov eax, [bp-4]`?  Or did you want to get the FP bit-pattern into an integer register?  IDK why you're dividing the low 16 bits of it by 10.

Comment: I want to get the FP bit-pattern into an integer register @PeterCordes

Comment: i Just want to display the floating point 1.5 in dosbox via eax, is this possible? how ?

Comment: So you want a decimal format.  It's probably easier to write a simple float-to-string using FP operations, rather than getting the bits that represent it into an integer register.  You could start with a float to int *conversion* to get the integer part, though.

Comment: Yup, turns out there's a simple algorithm which is probably good enough what you need.  Get the integer part with `fist` (and subtract it from your FP value with `fisub` or something), then keep multiplying by 10 to get fraction digits.  Or multiply by 10000 to get an integer with multiple fraction digits, and use the usual divide-by-10 algorithm to turn that into a string.  I linked this question to an existing one showing the algorithms.  Lots of other google hits for `site:stackoverflow.com assembly "float" to string` come up, too, so check them out if you want more detail.

Comment: @PeterCordes but when i use fist, if the value is 1.5 it will auto round off to 2 as a integer, is there another instruction to store integer without caring its floating point?

Comment: You mean truncate towards zero?  You can set the x87 rounding mode to truncate instead of the default round-to-nearest, or use SSE3 `fisttp` if DOSBOX emulates a CPU that support it.  Look at C compiler output (https://godbolt.org/g/ASFriN) from `int foo(float x) { return x; }` to see (32-bit) x87 code that does exactly that, and then sets it back.