# arithmetic operations using float binary "0b"

Tags: c, binary, ieee-754

I'm trying to understand, I'm a beginner.

I want to do arithmetic operations with float numbers in binary.

I was using http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html to do the conversion

Only he returns me:

```
1069547520.000000
1069547520.000000
2139095040.000000
```

What is it?

I was hoping for this:

```
00111111110000000000000000000000
00111111110000000000000000000000
01000000010000000000000000000000
```

%f in printf() would be wrong too?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        float a = 0b00111111110000000000000000000000; /* 1.5 */
        float b = 0b00111111110000000000000000000000; /* 1.5 */
        float c;

        c = a + b; /* 3.0 !? */

        printf("%f\n", a);
        printf("%f\n", b);
        printf("%f\n", c);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "I want to do arithmetic operations with float numbers in binary." All arithmetic operations on all scalar types are done in binary. What do you \*really\* want?

Comment: I know the value that is returning me that I do not understand

Answer (score 4):

The binary constant `0b00111111110000000000000000000000` is an [extension of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html), and it has type *`int`* having value `1069547520`. This is converted to a float by the same value, i.e. the float closest to 1069547520.

There is no way of having floating point constants in binary in C; but hex is possible. If there were, then 1.5 would be expressed in binary simply as something like

```
0b1.1f
```

i.e. its numeric value in binary is `1.1`.

C17 (C99, C11) does have support for *hexadecimal floating point constants*; you can use

```
0x1.8p0f
```

for `1.5f`; `p0` signifies the exponent.

If you really want to fiddle with the IEEE 754 binary format, you need to use an union or `memcpy`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    float a;
    uint32_t a_v = 0b00111111110000000000000000000000;

    memcpy(&a, &a_v, sizeof(float));
    printf("%f\n", a);
    // prints 1.500000 on linux x86-64
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have to make thousands of calculations with several giant csv files, so I figured that if I use binary it would be faster because it would avoid the conversion, that is, how I could do aritimeticas operations this way that you put

Comment: @FabioFontes well, in that case, **no, this isn't going to do anything faster**. The compiler **will convert 1.5f to the binary representation automatically**.

Comment: Suggest adding the standard hex option, which I think would be `0x1.8p0`.

Comment: @chux thanks, added. Though I doubt this will help op

Comment: Note C99 and C11 support [hexadecimal floating constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4825824/2410359).

Comment: @chux they're obsolete ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your binary literals are *integer* literals. Then you print the floating point values *as* floating point values, not using binary representation.