# Literals e and f in floating point representation in c

Tags: c, math, floating-point

Can someone explain what does literals e and f mean while representing a floating point in c ?
for eg

```
float f = 6.8558e-4f
```

Comment: What does your books, tutorials or teacher say?

Comment: To be honest, this isn't really a C question. The use of "E" or "e" to indicate an exponent is absolutely ubiquitous in math and scientific computing. Even Excel understands it ;) Having said that, I guess it's possible that a person might see it for the first time in a programming course.

Answer (score 2):

From the 2018 C standard, clause 6.4.4.2, reworded:

- “A floating constant has a *significand part* that may be followed by an *exponent part* and a suffix that specifies its type.”
- The significand is a sequence of digits that may include a period. It represents a number in the usual way. For example, 3.4 represents 3 ones and 4 tenths.
- The exponent part is an `e` or `E` followed by an optional sign and a sequence of digits, such as `e13` or `e-4`.
- The “exponent indicates the power of 10 by which the significand part is to be scaled.”
- “An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If suffixed by the letter `f` or `F`, it has type `float`. If suffixed by the letter `l` or `L`, it has type `long double`.”

Thus `6.8558e-4f` represents 6.8558•10<sup>−4</sup> and produces a `float` value.

Note that most C implementations use a `float` format based on powers of 2, not 10, so they cannot represent 6.8558•10<sup>−4</sup> exactly. In the format commonly used, IEEE-754 binary32, the closest representable value is 0.0006855800165794789791107177734375.

Answer (score 1):

The `e` indicates scientific notation. So `6.8558e-4` is equivalent to 6.8558×10<sup>−4</sup>.

The `f` is a suffix that indicates a floating-point number. (Floating-point numbers are treated as double precision by default.)

Incidentally, C99 also introduced a hexadecimal notation for floating point numbers, which you can read about here: [hexadecimal floating constant in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4825824/1679849)

Comment: `long double` constants have suffix `l` (or `L`), not `lf`. `double` constants have no suffix.