# Floating point number notation in C language

Tags: c, floating-point, signal-processing, stm32

Whati is `p` in `const float Q31_MAX_F =  0x0.FFFFFFp0F;`? Generally what is `a`, `b` and `c` in 0x`a`.`b`p`c`?

Does this expression explicitely define binary stored in `float32_t`?

I have serached for it in web but doesn't find anything.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825824/hexadecimal-floating-constant-in-c

Comment: @Armandas thx then this is a duplicate.

Comment: But I still not completely understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `F` at the end of `0x0.FFFFFFp0F` makes this interesting.

---

> What is p in `const float Q31_MAX_F =  0x0.FFFFFFp0F;`?

`p` is the exponential indicator for some floating point hexadecimal * 2<sup>decimal power of 2</sup>.

It is 0x0.FFFFFF * p<sup>decimal power of 2</sup>, not some hexadecimal exponent `0F`.

`F` at the end of `0x0.FFFFFFp0F` (more commonly an `f`) indicates the constant is a `float` and not a `double`. The `F` is not part of the exponent. The *value* is `0x0.FFFFFF*pow(2,0)` or *exactly* 0.999999940395355224609375

---

> Generally what is a, b and c in 0xa.bpc?

With `0x0.FFFFFFp0F`, `a` is 0, `b` is the hexadecimal fraction `0.FFFFFF` or <sup>16,777,215</sup>/<sub>16,777,216</sub> or 0.999999940395355224609375 and `c` is 0.

---

> Does this expression explicitly define binary stored in `float32_t`?

With an `F` or `f` suffix, `0x0.FFFFFFp0F` is a constant of type `float`.

`float32_t` is not a standard C type.

Comment: Could you please update your question for general form according to my update? I can't understand what is `p^(decimal power of 2)`

Comment: And what is that F in exponent?

Comment: `F` in `p0F` indicate the constant is a `float` and not a `double`.  It is not part of the exponent.  The _value_ is `0x0.FFFFFF*pow(2,0)`