# Converting hexadecimal floating constant to 64-bit binary representation

Tags: floating-point, hex

I have seen [examples](https://observablehq.com/@jrus/hexfloat)/[references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)/[previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825824/hexadecimal-floating-constant-in-c), but I cannot seem to get my head around some of the cases.

To be more specific, when the numbers is `0x1.MMMMMpEEE`, then I can parse out the mantissa representation, which is `MMMMM` and the exponent, which is `EEE` and convert them to binary representation. Putting them all together will give me what I want.

However, in cases like `0x8.60a91c16b9b28p-4` or `0x7.ffffffffffffcp-4`, because of the `8` and `7` after the `0x`, how do I parse this hexadecimal mantissa into bit-wise binary representation?

Comment: Divide digit string by power of two such that resultant significand part is in [1,2). Adjust exponent accordingly.  So for the first example divide by 8 and adjust exponent by 3; for second example divide by four and adjust exponent by 2.

Comment: @njuffa when you say "divide digit string by power of two", can you elaborate a bit more on this? Is this a bit shifting operator?

Comment: For positive operands, x / 2**n = x >> n. Example  `0x8.60a91c16b9b28p-4` turns into `0x1.0c152382d7365p-1`, which can already be handled successfully per the question.