# p in Hexadecimal floating point constant

Tags: c++, c++17

C++17 allows defining floating point constants in hexadecimal format like

```cpp
double d1 = 0x1.2p3;    // 9.0
double d2 = 0x1.86Ap+16 // 100000.0
```

In hexadecimal floating point constants the mantissa and exponent is separated using the letter `p|P`.

Why C++ standard committee decided to use the letter `p|P` instead of any other letter?

They could not have used the normal `e|E` notation in hex floating point constant because letter `e|E` is part of hexadecimal digit. But they could have used letter `g|G` which is usually used in `printf` format specifier for floating point value, or any other letter. Is there any specific reason for using the letter `p`?

Comment: I have voted to close this as "opinion based" ... but there are other reasons why this could be closed. What is it that you want, as an answer?

Comment: I think it's part of IEEE 754 see __Hexadecimal literals__ here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754  _"...the standard recommends providing conversions to and from external hexadecimal-significand character sequences, based on C99's hexadecimal floating point literals....an exponent indicator "p"  ... "_

Comment: What is the reasoning for using letter `p` in hexadecimal floating point constant?

Comment: `p` for power I'd guess

Comment: @RichardCritten so like most things weird in C++, the answer is "blame C" :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hexadecimal floating constant in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825824/hexadecimal-floating-constant-in-c)

Comment: @Orace That doesn't explain why `p` was chosen over any other letter, which is what this question is asking. But it does seem more appropriate as a C question, considering that C++ just chose to be consistent with C.

Comment: `e` wouldn't work because it's a hexadecimal digit.

Comment: Could also be the first letter of exponent that was usable with `e` and `x` not being suitable

Comment: @RichardHodges The question already acknowledges that, but asks why `g`, which was already used in `printf`/`scanf`, wasn't chosen.

Comment: [The proposal](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0245r0.html) says "There is a base-2 scientific notation for floating point values: 0x3.ABCp-10" but I'm having a hard time finding the origin of the notation.

Comment: @RyanHaining How is that base-2? Base 2 would be `0b11.1010'1011'1100p-10`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Quoting the linked proposal: *" The significand is given in hexadecimal, and the exponent is given in decimal and interpreted with respect to base 2"*

Comment: @Bob__ Still odd then, shouldn't it be 0x1.D5Ep-9? Normalized floating point only has 1 bit before the decimal point.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow like how 1.5e3 = 1.5 * 10^3, 0x5p3 = 0x5 * 2^3. [run this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t5MALcrLH15ARF32) which shows 0x1p10 = 1024

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think that's just an example of valid syntax. I'm not sure whether the choice between different possible representations is somehow specified for [outputted](https://godbolt.org/z/Evb9obY74) values.

Comment: @RyanHaining Yes, it is neat. The hexadecimal part is exactly the mantisse (+leading 1 bit) and the exponent is exactly the exponent in the float/double. It makes it real easy to correctly printf or scanf those numbers. None of the rounding horrors the other formats have to find the nearest number. The format is exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Hexadecimal_exponential_notation :

> By convention, the letter P (or p, for "power") represents *times two raised to the power of*, [...]

> Why C++ standard committee decided to use the letter p|P instead of any other letter?

Because it was so in C. It wasn't in [B](https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/expl/b/manu/manu.html#Section2_4), so must have been something added to C.

> Is there any specific reason for using the letter p?

Not really.